# Output a request header of a Restful web service in Java

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

My requirement is simple. I just can't figure out how to do this. I just started my adventure in learning Rest web services with java. My requirement here is to find the header part of the request to the following web service method.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Path("/html")
public String getUserHtml(@Context HttpHeaders h){

    System.out.println(h.toString());
    String responce = "<h1>Hi m8!</h1>";
    return responce;
}
```

As you can see I have tried out something, but this outputs org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest@c290c6b

That is not what I want. Can some one tell me how to output the whole header string. I also tried out getHeaderString method but don't know what the argument should be. Thanks.

Comment: Try using getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) This should probably get you the content type set in request. Please refer https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html for more information.

Comment: thanks. will give it a try when I get the time.

Comment: thanks again. This gives me null. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check if it's set in request header.

Answer (score 1):

You can get request header details by calling getRequestHeaders() method of HttpHeaders which will return MultivaluedMap<> object -

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> reauestHeaders = h.getRequestHeaders();
```

Iterate over this map to get the header details.